# Eloquent: updating multiple MorphMany relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have 2 models bound by a MorphMany relationship:

```
class Membership extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'status',
        'since',
        'owned_by',
    ];

    public function payments(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Payment::class, 'payable');
    }
}


class Payment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'status',
        'amount',
        'currency',
    ];

    public function payable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

I want to update the status attribute of all the payments that belong to the memberships that have their status set to "pending"
Is it possible to do this with Eloquent ?

EDIT:
I want to update all the payments that have their status attribute set to "pending" and  that belong to the memberships that have also their status set to "pending"

Comment: `Membership::where('status', 'something')->payments()->update(['status' => 'something_new']);`can work?

Comment: @Jack I don't know, but I realized that my question was incomplete. You can now read the correct question above in the "edit" part.

Comment: `Membership::where('status', 'something')->payments()->where('status', 'something')->update(['status' => 'something_new']);`